# Adding a new row to a Google Doc with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I work at a school with 500 students and am working on a script that automatically generates report card comment templates in Docs for teachers. I am adept with Google Sheets and scripts but haven't done much with Docs, so I'm struggling.

Here is an [example of the template](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Gwej20sa9o5rV8d4herPrHuaVHe9BGEohcdOIiOJJcY/edit?usp=sharing) Doc.

The goal of the script is to create a new row on the table in the template. In the first column, student names will be placed. There will be a new row for each student. The other columns should be created, but left blank. Here is an example of what it would look like after a class with two students is added.

[image]

```
function docCreator() {
  var docId = makeACopy("123");
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = document.getBody();
  var studentList = getStudentList; //returns student list as array

  body.replaceText('#{Heading}', "Report Cards (Semester 1) 2022");
  var table = body.getTables();
  for (b = 0; b < studentList.length; b++) {
    var tr = table[0].appendTableRow();
    var td = tr.appendTableCell(studentList[b]);
  }

  document.saveAndClose()
}
```

When I run the program, it puts the names underneath the table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following technique:

```js
function docCreator() {
  const studentList = ['John', 'Jane', 'Lana']; //returns student list as array
  const body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.replaceText('#{Heading}', "Report Cards (Semester 1) 2022");
  const table = body.getTables()[0];
  const style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
  for (i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
    const tr = table.getRow(1).copy();
    tr.getCell(0).setText(studentList[i]).setAttributes(style);
    for (let i = 1; i < tr.getNumCells(); i++) tr.getCell(i).clear().setAttributes(style);
    table.appendTableRow(tr);
  }
}
```

I mocked your `getStudentList` of course, and didn't actually create a copy of the template, but the rest is good.

The idea is that you create a copy of the second row, replace its content as needed, and append it to the table. I also use the `style` object to remove the `bold` font from the content.

Let me know if this does the trick for you or if you need me to amend the answer.